# ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'null': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.NullHandler': No module named NullHandler

Tags: python, django

I am getting error while running python manage.py runserver of all the django projects which i have. I am using django 1.6.

My projects were running perfectly fine. Then I installed django-subdomains and django-gcm packages in my virtual environment for some implementations and the error started showing up in all the projects (may be this has something to do with the error so I mentioned). Then I uninstalled the packages but the error remains

MY error stack trace is:

```
    Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at    0xabcddf4>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/shivam/virtual/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/virtual/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/shivam/virtual/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 249, in raise_last_exception
six.reraise(*_exception)
  File "/home/shivam/virtual/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/shivam/virtual/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/home/shivam/virtual/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/log.py", line 71, in configure_logging
logging_config_func(logging_settings)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 575, in configure
'%r: %s' % (name, e))
```

ValueError: Unable to configure handler 'null': Cannot resolve 'django.utils.log.NullHandler': No module named NullHandler

Comment: are you using version control?  can you diff to the last version that was working? Notice the last two files are not in your virtual environment

Comment: @joelgoldstick yeah i just noticed that last two files are not from my virtual environment, but i don't understand why they are being accessed. And also i don't know how to roll back to the previous working version. Please help